# How to render object as HTML in JSP

Tags: html, jsp, struts2, el

I've a question about rendering an object in my application.

Let's say I have an object who needs to display in differents places of the application but always with the same template.

If I do something like this:

```java
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import static org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml;

public class RegulDeclarationPersoDTO {

    private static final List<String> TYPES_RETRAIT = Arrays.asList(
            "TYPE_REGUL#1",
            "TYPE_REGUL#2",
            "TYPE_REGUL_AC#3",
            "TYPE_REGUL_AC#4",
            "TYPE_REGUL_AC#5");

    private static final String BG_COLOR_RETRAIT = "#FF6347";
    private static final String BG_COLOR_DEPASSSEMENT = "#FFB431";

    private Integer id;
    private BigDecimal horaire;
    private BigDecimal horaireReel;
    private Integer declId;
    private String commentaire;
    private Integer histoId;
    private ValeursDTO declaration;
    private String type;
    private String render;

    public String getRender() {
        render = String.format(
                "<tr>" +
                "<td><i class='fa fa-circle' style='color: %s'></i></td>" +
                "<td style='text-align: center'> %s h </td>" +
                "<td style='text-align: center'> %s h </td>" +
                "<td style='text-align: right'> %s </td>" +
                "</tr>",
                TYPES_RETRAIT.contains(type) ? BG_COLOR_RETRAIT : BG_COLOR_DEPASSSEMENT,
                horaire.stripTrailingZeros(),
                horaire.stripTrailingZeros(),
                escapeHtml(commentaire)
        );
        return render;
    }
}
```

from my JSP I can do this to render my object into the table:

```
${myObject.render}
```

I simplified case but in more complex case where I need add some business logic into the JSP is it a good way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not good. DTO is a data object which should contain only data. To render html table you should use JSP tags, or javascript if you want to create a table while rendering a document.

```
${myObject.render}
```

EL output in JSP is dangerous because it doesn't escape XSS symbols. In Struts2 all UI tags escape HTML texts. You should use them to render text only that should be escaped.

Comment: I understand the point of not mixing rendering with dto.

Speaking of rendering, let's say I have an array with multiple values ​​for with columns from January to December. In the dto containing the values ​​of the array, I have the list of corrections and I have to use loops and mix that with jquery in my jsp and I find that the code quickly becomes confused whereas if my generated object are rendered I have easier access to its properties. Are there no other approaches possible with a utility class for rendering for example?

Comment: I edited my question with a more specific example.My idea was that processing conditions is easier if I can process my evaluators directly from the class than if I had to do it in the JSP part.

Comment: As I said in this answer it is not good. JSP is a servlet and you can render your object there without having bad idea of misunderstanding concepts of programming in Java. You can also use templates to render HTML using different templating frameworks. If you think that you can use data object as a view is incorrect from the MVC point, however Struts controllers are value objects regarding this pattern.